# Is it possible to run plsql package under hplsql command using hplsql -f package.sql

Tags: plsql, hive-hplsql

I am trying to run a  PL/SQL package which contains a procedure with cursor (with parameter) and also procedure with 3 parameters will it work fine in hplsql.

Something like:

```
create package name as
procedure proc( with 3 input parameters )
end package;

create or replace package body as
variables declaration like variable -schema name .table name %type
 cursor cursor name(4 parameters)
select variables 
from
columns
procedure proc(parameters)
open cursor 
fetch into
close
end proc
end package
```

Comment: You must try yourself and let others know if this works fine or not

Comment: i have the .sql file but i am unable to upload that can u please help me